# Angular directive to pass a attribute on one textbox to another div button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have one textbox which has some attributes.

```
<input type="text" code=1 add-Me>
```

And I have one div which is hidden at first.

```
<div ng-show="hideMe">
    <input type="button" onclick="GetElements(code);">
</div>
```

So my question here is, I want to make a directive on a click of F2(when the focus is on textbox ), I want to open that hidden div and focus on that button inside div and pass the textbox attribute on that button click.

So far I have made an attribute:

```
app.directive('addMe', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
           // console.log(scope.$parent.data.name);
            if (event.which === 113) {

               // What to do now??
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a similar scenario while working with a modal. I came up with a solution using $rootScope. You can call a function while a user changes the first input --

```
<input type="text" code=1 onclick/onchange="setValueToRootScope(code)">
```

Now,  in your *GetElements()* function, check the value of the *$rootScope.ur_variable* and perform operation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

**In your JS:**

```
app.directive('addMe', function () {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
       // console.log(scope.$parent.data.name);
        if (event.which === 113) {

           $scope.codeVar=element.getAttribute("code");
$scope.hideMe=true;

        }
    });
};
});
```

- Your div will be displayed since the variable "hideMe" has been set to true.
- And the value of your code attribute as well is stored in the "codeVar" variable in the $scope so that it can be accessed in that particular controller's scope.

**In the HTML part:(If your GetElements function is under your controller's scope)**

```
<div ng-show="hideMe">
<input type="button" ng-click="GetElements(codeVar);">
</div>
```